# JSON.parse overwrite to handle passing in objects

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I have a legacy system I'm maintaining. We are in the process of setting JSON response content to "application/json" (from "text/plain"). Since the responses were interpreted as plain text before there is a fairly substantial number of places where the code calls `JSON.parse`. We found that when we make the change, the parsing breaks since the response is now interpreted as a JSON object, which cannot be passed to `JSON.parse` without an error.

Now the obvious solution is to go in and properly fix all these in coordination with the back-end changes, but it's A LOT. As a stop-gap measure and to make sure nothing gets broken, I'd like to add the following code. The idea is, if the passed input is already an object it simply gets returned. Anything else goes to the proper `JSON.parse`.

```
  //handle loose JSON parsing
  JSON.strictParse = JSON.parse;
  JSON.parse = function (input, reviver) {
    if (typeof input == "object") return input;
       return JSON.strictParse(input, reviver);
  }
```

My question is, is this a terrible idea, and if so why? The only thing I can think of is if some library somehow relied on the original behaviour, but that seems fairly far fetched.

Comment: I can't see how a library would want to parse an already parsed object, so that should be fine, although I wouldn't say its "best practice". What's the problem with just removing all the `JSON.parse()` in the responses? You can use a find/replace all feature, and at least in vs code it's possible to get through each found JSON.parse and replace them individually, to make sure you don't break other uses of JSON.parse. But no it's not a terrible idea, if it actually works.

Comment: I would avoid replacing internal behavior. This is a bad idea. Couldn't you wrap you HTTP calls and stringify their responses, so they will be properly parsed? (I know it is ugly, but I also know fixing legacy code sucks. At least that would mimic the current behavior without messing around with internal implementation)

Comment: Can you post an example of how you are fetching these endpoints?

Answer (score 4):

The most robust solution is obviously to refactor the codebase. That being said, I'll provide an answer about your idea.

According to the spec: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/11.0/index.html#sec-json.parse, the output of `JSON.parse` can be of the following types:

- `string`
- `number`
- `boolean`
- `null`
- `Array`
- `Object`

The results of `JSON.parse` for types `number`, `boolean` and `null` can safely be passed again to `JSON.parse`:

```js
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.parse('23')));
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.parse('true')));
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.parse('null')));
```

However, this is not the case for objects and arrays which are taken their `toString()` representation and that makes `JSON.parse` fail.

```js
console.log([1, 2, 3].toString());
console.log({ property: 'value' }.toString());

JSON.parse([1, 2, 3]);
JSON.parse({ property: 'value' });
```

So you can safely assume that no library calls `JSON.parse` with an `Array` or `Object` as first parameter. You are currently filtering them out, so this is fine so far.

When it comes to strings, this is an edge case that makes your solution unsafe:

```js
const string = JSON.parse('"Some text"');
// The result of this is a string, it will fail if passed again to JSON.parse
console.log(string);
JSON.parse(string);
```

You can't safely determine if a `string` is the output of a `JSON.parse` or not, so your solution is safe **only** if you can guarantee that no HTTP message is parsed as plain `string`:

```js
(function () {
    const nativeParse = JSON.parse;
    JSON.parse = function (input) {
        return typeof input === 'object'
            ? input
            : nativeParse(...arguments);
    }
})();

console.log(JSON.parse(23));
console.log(JSON.parse(true));
console.log(JSON.parse(null));
console.log(JSON.parse([1, 2, 3]));
console.log(JSON.parse({ property: 'value' }));
console.log(JSON.parse('Some text')); // This will fail, make sure it never happens
```

Don't forget the [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) to avoid polluting the global scope, and to keep the native `JSON.parse` unavailable to any other code. Also, make sure that this code runs **before** any other code.

Comment: Thank you for a very detailed answer. I have a few follow ups. It's my understanding that both arrays and objects will result in typeof value of "object". And for strings, based on my function, it would use the native string parsing.

Comment: You're right about arrays, I'm editing. What I mean about strings is that if the API returns `'"Some text"'` and it's automatically parsed as `'Some text'` your function will fail after that. That's an edge case but you need to make sure your API never returns plain strings before implementing this

Answer (score 0):

To change natives is always a bad idea exactly for the reason you said.

Actually this is an edge case, but if a library you are using trusts the Error thrown by `JSON.parse` you are going to break it.

If it's really so hard to find and replace all occurrences of `JSON.parse` in your project I would at least recommend something like:

```
//handle loose JSON parsing
JSON.strictParse = JSON.parse;
JSON.parse = function (input, reviver) {
  if (typeof input == "object") {
    console.log(new Error("JSON FIX ME"));

    return input;
  }

  return JSON.strictParse(input, reviver);
}
```

to help you finding all hidden occurrences and then remove it at all.

Answer (score 0):

As @Daniele Ricci says the best way if make a `console.log` message to fix all occurrences in your code as they appear (maybe you can generate a log file with all the stack of the `Error`.

Well, in my opinion, modify a build-in function in javascript is not recommended because you can make other errors in the project libraries. For example, a library can handle a try-catch when `JSON.parse` fails when an object is inserted.

But well, in the case that you know what you do, the technique to replace the build-in methods is called **"Monkey patching"**.

In javascript, you must be careful about the context of the code. If you want to modify the `JSON.parse` you don't know if internally how works. To fix that problem you can use [Function.apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).

For your case:

```js
const JSONParseOri = JSON.parse;
JSON.parse = function _parse() {
    if (typeof arguments[0] == "object") {
        return arguments[0];
    }
    return JSONParseOri.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

- When you use `arguments` and not `(input, revive)` you ensure you will respect all the "arguments" pass it to the Function.
- When you use `.apply(this, ...)` you ensure the context when "JSONParseOri" is running will be the correct.

The MDN doesn't have the good practices for "Monkey patching" but you can see a DOM example here: [Monkey patching DOM methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Add-ons/Overlay_Extensions/XUL_School/Appendix_F:_Monitoring_DOM_changes#Monkey_patching_DOM_methods)